# recursion gives the wrong answer without error but I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to solve a problem about calculate how much payment you need clear a credit balance in a year.
the annual interest is 0.2, the formula of the monthly balance is: (balance - monthly payment)+ (0.2/12)*(balance-monthly payment), which if I repeat this calculation 12 times, I can get the balance in the end of a year.
the hard part is to calculate the amount we need to clear an amount of balance in a year. Here is my code, It's running, but I can't figure out why it gives the wrong answer.

```
def clear(b,m,x):
    while m !=0:
        b=(b-x)+(0.2/12)*(b-x)
        x=x        
        m-=1
    if m == 0 and b<= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return clear(b,m+12,x+20)
    




m=12
b=3329
x=20
print(clear(b, m, x))
```

the test value 3329 should return 310 but my code return 160...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tracing is always a good place to start. Make your `while` loop log the values it iterates through, and make your function log the values it's called with; between those two things you should be able to figure out what's going on, if not enough to solve the problem yourself, enough to write a more specific question about the technical problem identified.

Comment: Just at a glance, the two things that look suspicious are `x=x` (which does nothing) and `m + 12` (which as far as I can tell is equivalent to just `12` as `m` is guaranteed to be 0 at this point as that's the exit condition of the while loop).

Comment: Thanks，I ve tried python tutor to figure out all the scope problems and iteration problems, I kinda think that my coding direction got messed up but I really don't know what's wrong with it and always a better solution code will be very helpful to me!(I will compare other's code and learn so I may also learn how to solve this kind of problem... Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Thank you! the m+12 is working as I check the scope value change but I will check again with that x=x!

Comment: I haven't figured out your problem yet. But note that this is your code, the rest are just adding to confusion: ```def clear(b, m, x):
    while m != 0:
        b = (b-x)+(0.2/12)*(b-x)
        m -= 1

    if b <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return clear(b, 12, x+20)```

Comment: Shouldn't b continually go down? Is your formula correct? Cuz b first goes up before going down again

Comment: tsk re-za, u r right, I just figured out why it's wrong! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help, I figured out why...
And to people may see this question, please remember the recursion return the value from the the formula scope to global scope...
In my code, it returns b in the end which the value of b is changing with the scope... In my case, from x=20-about 60, the balance is increasing but after 100, it decreased each time while b return itself from formula scope to global scope.
for example, when x=60, value of b increased to about 6000, but when it's 100 or 120, it decreased to about 2000-3000, then in x=160, the value of b is less then 0 and my code takes it as the result...
here is the right code! after I fixed the value of b inside the recursion, it working properly!

```
def clear(b,m,x):
    b=4773
    while m !=0:
        b=(b-x)*(0.2/12+1)
        m-=1
    if m == 0 and b<= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return clear(b,m+12,x+10)
    




m=12
b=3329
x=20
print(clear(b, m, x))
```